# Math behind Pareto chart of standardized effects from Minitab

Tags: regression, hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance, multiple-regression

I would like to understand the math behind the graph that Minitab computes explained [here](https://support.minitab.com/en-us/minitab/18/help-and-how-to/modeling-statistics/doe/how-to/factorial/analyze-factorial-design/interpret-the-results/all-statistics-and-graphs/effects-plots/), which I have encountered a couple of times in publications regarding regression modeling such as [this](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/269692925_Applications_of_Experimental_Design_and_Response_Surface_Method_in_Probabilistic_Geothermal_Resource_Assessment_-_Preliminary_Results), [this](https://www.redalyc.org/journal/3032/303265671058/html/).

[image: Chart Example]

According to the Minitab website, the bar is composed of the terms/model input variables/independent variables in the bars. It has a vertical line that shows a reference score, of which variables with values bigger than that are significant.

I believe the variable values are computed or related with T-Statistc (t term) value computed for each model term. This can be seen from the image below taken from [link](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/269692925_Applications_of_Experimental_Design_and_Response_Surface_Method_in_Probabilistic_Geothermal_Resource_Assessment_-_Preliminary_Results).

[image]

I still dont know where the standardize word come into effect, e.g. are the T-Statistics standardazied after being computed ? Also is standardized coming from effect size [defintion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Effect_size) or z-score [conversion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_score) ?

I believe the reference score comes from the Student-T table critical values, since all the graphs I inspected so far have their values covered in the two-tail student-t table. Yet still unsure how they are being looked up e.g. how the degrees of freedom are being defined for each case.

My goal is to understand the math so I can replicate in a python code. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the length of the bar is the ratio `abs(Coeff) / SE Coeff`  eg for temp = 42.25 / 16.29 = 2.59 (this almost equals the value where the vertical bar is drawn, as a visual check). As @zphisto mentioned, the vertical line comes from a two-tailed T test at the appropriate confidence limit and degrees of freedom `dof` (5 in this case).  AFAIK "standardised" in this context means dividing the effect size by an estimate of the error, which is basically related to the standard deviation.  `Effect` in the MiniTab output is the difference between the average of all the responses (Power in this case) at the +1 level and -1 level for each parameter.  These responses are used to fit a linear model based on the average response, hence why `Coeff` is `Effect / 2`.  Not entirely sure how MiniTab calculates `SE Coeff` but the following code seems to work:

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.stats

terms = ["temperature", "porosity", "permeability", "frac spacing", "well depth", "boundary"]

levels = [[ 1,  1,  1, -1,  1,  1],
[-1,  1, -1, -1, -1,  1],
[-1,  1,  1, -1,  1, -1],
[ 1,  1, -1,  1,  1, -1],
[-1, -1, -1,  1,  1,  1],
[-1,  1,  1,  1, -1,  1],
[-1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1],
[ 1,  1, -1,  1, -1, -1],
[-1, -1,  1,  1,  1, -1],
[ 1, -1,  1, -1, -1, -1],
[ 1, -1,  1,  1, -1,  1],
[ 1, -1, -1, -1,  1,  1]]

levels = np.array(levels)
n, k = np.shape(levels)
power = np.array([53.0, 65.0, 59.0, 129.0, 48.0, 213.0, 39.0, 125.0, 89.0, 255.0, 361.0, 97.0])
rewop = np.reshape(power, (-1, 1))

x = rewop * levels
coeff = x.sum(axis=0) / n

pmean = np.mean(power)
y = coeff * levels
p_est = pmean + y.sum(axis=1)

sse = np.sum((power - p_est) ** 2)
std = np.std(power, ddof=1)
sec = sse / std / (n - 2)

dof = n - k - 1
tval = coeff / sec
pval = 2.0 * (1.0 - scipy.stats.t.cdf(np.abs(tval), df=dof, loc=0, scale=1))    # two-tailed distribution

print("Term           Effect     Coef   SE Coef      T      P ")

t = pmean / sec
p = 2.0 * (1.0 - scipy.stats.t.cdf(t, df=dof, loc=0, scale=1))    
print(f"Constant               {pmean:7.2f}     {sec:5.2f}  {t:5.2f}  {p:5.3f}")

for q, c, t, p in zip(terms, coeff, tval, pval):
    print(f"{q:12s}  {2.0*c:7.2f}  {c:7.2f}     {sec:5.2f}  {t:5.2f}  {p:5.3f}")
```

This gives this output:

```
Term           Effect     Coef   SE Coef      T      P 
Constant                127.75     16.22   7.88  0.001
temperature     84.50    42.25     16.22   2.61  0.048
porosity       -40.83   -20.42     16.22  -1.26  0.264
permeability    87.83    43.92     16.22   2.71  0.042
frac spacing    66.17    33.08     16.22   2.04  0.097
well depth     -97.17   -48.58     16.22  -3.00  0.030
boundary        23.50    11.75     16.22   0.72  0.501
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically Minitab compares the t-statistic from each factor to the value corresponding to the error.
So the bars length is T-Value in your table (e.g. 7.85, 2.59, ...) and the reference line is the critical point in the t distribution that corresponds to 1-alpha/2 probability. (eg. alpha = 0.05, p=0.975)
The degrees of freedom to evaluate are the ones corresponding to the error (dof erorr = #totalruns-#terms-1 not including the intercept, i.e. n-P-1).

For the first picture with k=3 factors, 2 levels and 2 replicates: n=1 and P=8 d.o.f = 2^3*2-8=8
For the second picture with n=12 P=6 d.o.f = 12-6-1=5

In Python:

```py
>>> from scipy import stats

>>> stats.t.ppf(1-0.025,8)
2.3060041350333704

>>> stats.t.ppf(1-0.025, 5)
2.5705818366147395
```

That would correspond to the values you have in your sample images.